# What does Poctob mean?

Tags: узус

I'm doing a research report on Rostov Veliky for a Geography class. I have no experience in Russian and I lack understanding of geography in general. The map refers to it as Poctov and I can not translate it into English using google, I tried.

I can only guess but is this the Russian word for Rostov, why wouldn't it use Russian characters? If not please explain what it is. If it is, please let me know if Russians would call Rostov Veliky, Poctob Veliky.

here it is: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rostov,+Yaroslavl+Oblast,+Russia/@57.1968466,39.3805101,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x46b3204f23a50833:0xa4f3079f91ac13e0

Sorry, very confused here.

Comment: Ростов Великий.
Rostov Velikii.
And do not use Poctob or Poctov. It is wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rostov provides Russian spelling too. Vote to close.

Comment: It may be over obvious to you, but all it says is Poctov. It doesn't explain what it is or means.

Comment: It does say two spellings of the same word using Latin and Cyrillic alphabets. "Poctob" is just some error which you found somewhere else.

Comment: POCTOB (poctob) is actually capital cyrillic letters for ростов - РОСТОВ.

Comment: Could you please attach a photo or screenshot of the map?

Comment: I'm with @Artemix on this one, nice catch.

Comment: @Quassnoi I've added a link to where I seen it on google maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Poctob** is the Russian word **Ростов**, 'Rostov' written in the English letters that look closest to the Russian ones.